# Fixed data table for pagination

Tags: reactjs, fixed-data-table

How to implement the **pagination** with `fixed-data-table`?

I want to implement the pagination with `fixed-data-table`. According to the [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/api-table-v0.5.html), we must set the height to it so that i can calculate the `visible zone` to show the rows.

Is there a way to do that? Any tricky way are also welcome. Thx.

Comment: according to what document? Can you provide a link? I've got the same question but there's not much here to work with.

Comment: Just check [this page](http://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/api-table-v0.5.html). `Either height or maxHeight must be specified.`

Comment: if you edit your answer with the link, I'd give your question an upvote! (I can't change my vote until its edited according to SO)

Comment: Alright, fare enough. Just added a link to `the fixed-data-table document` in my answer. : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a way to do that.

Set `maxHeight` to `Table`. According to [the fixed-data-table document](http://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/api-table-v0.5.html), we must set either `height` **or** `maxHeight`. My bad. ***It's better to read more documents.***

Another thing is, if we are using the **responsive-fixed-data-table** then it's not possible to set the `maxHeight` for now. Because this wrapper simply set `height: 100%`.

I will send a PR later.